# Change polymer attributes externally

Tags: attributes, polymer

I see a lot of questions regarding on how to listen for changes in attributes. But none on how to actually change them.

Even in debug, I can't find the attributes in the object tree. How do I achieve this? is there a more polymeric way of doing the following ?

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="owner">
  <template>
    <p id="el">{{owner}}</p>
  </template>
  <script>
        Polymer({
            owner: "Miguel",
        });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<my-element id="el1" owner="blabla"></my-element>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("el1").owner = "Mary"
    })
</script>
```

It prints blablab, but doesn't change it to Mary

Comment: I feel this is one of the most basic things to do, and yet I can't find it in the official docs or on the web. How hard can it be ?

Answer (score 0):

In 0.5, you need to wait for `polymer-ready`. See docs [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#polymer-ready).

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="path/to/x-foo.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(e) {
      var xFoo = document.querySelector('x-foo');
      xFoo.barProperty = 'baz';
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Ideally, your app would be one element like `<my-app></my-app>` so that you'd have a binding for the `owner` attribute like so:

```
<my-element owner="{{owner}}"></my-element>
```

And `my-element` would reside in another Polymer element in which you can set the owner attribute like so:

```
// Parent Polymer element
Polymer({ 
  _someFunctionYouCall: function() {
   this.owner = 'Mary';
  }
});
```

Comment: so, I can only modify nested elements ? Is this.owner shared through the parent? once it was declared in the child element?

Comment: how do you know it's 0.5 ?

Comment: I wanted to learn this, but it's starting to look like a huge mess with no consistency whatsoever....

Comment: You're using `<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="owner">` === v0.5

Comment: The two-way binding `{{owner}}` enables the parent and child to update the same value and have it reflected in each element.

Comment: what if I have two child's of the same element and I change the owner in the parent it changes all of them ?

Comment: I actually downloaded v1.0, but when I do <dom module id="my-element"> i get errors saying it can't infere "name"

Comment: Share your code....have you properly registered the element with `is:'my-element'`?